# How to define const in Firebase Cloud Functions Typescript

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

The error that I am getting: Unhandled error ReferenceError: COLLECTION_A is not defined! 
When I upload code is no complaints about the code. I do have a need to use the same constant in multiple files. I tried to use `namespace` but it is not allowed...

How do I need to define constants that will be accessible in every file?

I have multiple files in src foldes:
index.ts 
foo.ts
boo.ts
cnst.ts

Inside index.ts:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
admin.initializeApp()

export * from './foo'
export * from './boo'
```

Inside cnst.ts:

```
const COLLECTION_A = "pathA"
const COLLECTION_B = "pathB"
```

Inside foo.ts I am trying to access const from cnst.ts

```
...
admin
        .firestore()
        .collection(COLLECTION_A)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out! But I don't like it!

Is there any better approach?? Or more correct in terms of good practice. I don't like this approach very much as a variable can be changed, But it should be const!!

inside cnst.ts I defined a new class:

```
export class Const {
    static COLLECTION_A = "pathA"
    static COLLECTION_B = "pathB"
}
```

And inside foo.ts I import it like this:

```
import { Const } from './cnst'
...    
...
    .collection(Const.COLLECTION_A)
...
```

---

I figured out also approach with constants:

inside cnst.ts

```
export const COLLECTION_A = "pathA"
export const COLLECTION_B = "pathB"
```

And inside foo.ts I import it like this:

```
import { COLLECTION_A } from './cnst'
...    
...
    .collection(COLLECTION_A)
...
```

I like second approach more since I am using constants. Is there any other way that would be suitable for my case?

Comment: I tried this way but it keeps getting me an error 
`export const MONTHLY = "MONTHLY";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the `outFile` flag. According to [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) this flag allows user to:

> Concatenate and emit output to single file. The order of concatenation
> is determined by the list of files passed to the compiler on the
> command line along with triple-slash references and imports.

This strategy will scale with your program much better than manually referencing specific files everywhere.

Check [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-am-i-getting-the-error-ts5055-cannot-write-file-xxxjs-because-it-would-overwrite-input-file-when-using-javascript-files) for more details.